# Moving to another activity in 2 seconds

Tags: java, android, android-handler

I'm a beginner to Android development, and am creating an offline app. I have three activities. The first activity screen splashes to next activity after two seconds, after that when I click a button in the second activity it is not moving to the third activity.

Actually it had worked before I added this splashing concept. When I tried to implement this I just modified the code and that's working well for the timer but not for the other..

Here's my code for all activities:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity1.class);
           MainActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
           MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, 2000);
}
}
```

**MainActivity1.java:**

```
    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity2.class);
                            startActivity(intent);   

            }

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: What happening when you click on button in second activity ? pls add logcat if you have error !

Comment: @y.feizi : Sir,When i click button in second activity it doesnt go anywhere simply stay in the same page .

Comment: @karthika Did you add the activity in manifest file.Put Toast inside the button click event check the toast visible or not.

Comment: @Yugesh : thank you sir ! That worked perfectly .. i made some mistake in android manifest file .. Thanks a lot !!! :)

Comment: @Yugesh Suggestion: turn your comment into an answer, so that the OP can accept it and remove the question from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Comment: @DerGolem Okay.i will add the answer..

Answer (score 1):

If you created activity class means, you must declare the activity in manifest file.Otherwise the activity should not be invoke or it show error in Run-time.

**Manifest file**

```
<activity 
 android:name=".MainActivity2">
</activity>
```